# Is there any way to know whether mediaplayer started or not

Tags: android, media-player

Hai guys I am new to android and i want to know is there any method to know whether the mediaplayer has already started ie when i call mediaplayer.start() does it return any value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have MediaPlayer instance object, then you can check with

```
    mediaPlayer.isPlaying();
```